# Why Photoshop changes the color after export even I use sRGB profile?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-profile, color-spaces

First, I created a new file in sRGB space:

[image]

Then I painted it with the color (255, 0, 0):

[image]

I double-checked that I'm working in sRGB:

[image]

Then I exported it:

[image]

Then the final result is still not shown as (255, 0, 0) in either Chrome or Preview!

[image]

What's going on here?

Comment: Your screen calibration/profile is miles out… somewhere. The first & last images are *approximately* the same, but the export pic is the only one even close to 255,0,0. First suspect is always that you have your Display Profile set as your working space, but as that's not the case you need to double-check your screen profile is actually correct & properly calibrated. Also check it appears in the list of options in 'working space' [but don't select it].

Comment: Do you have a a wide gamut monitor? Anyway your monitor is not calibrated as sRGB

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. Sorry. Not sure what's going on.  A PNG exported in sRGB with a colour #ff0000 (RGB 255,0,0) is [exactly the same](https://imgur.com/oFo7b7s) when viewed in Firefox. In Chrome and Edge it differs (255,1,0) ever so slightly. More likely this has something to do with your system setup.

Comment: Any chance you could share the actual PNG file, or the PSD?

Comment: I think I got it. I'll post my finding as an answer and could you guys please check if I'm mixing things up?

Comment: I dropped in a 2nd answer. I'm bothered by the Huion profile, as Pshop doesn't seem to know what to do with it, but more worried by Chrome, which is a million miles out of true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This isn't so much an answer as some ideas for methodology, work in progress.*

2nd Image from your answer, opened in Pshop & screen-shot **pasted** into here via Safari

[image]

Similar screenshot **posted** instead of pasted

[image]

The unfortunate discrepancy is if you look at the eyedropper colour, it says 226,61,36, yet both images in here are near-enough 255,0,0 - which means Pshop doesn't appear to know what to do with the Huion profile.
*Later…*
If I convert that to sRGB in Photoshop **then** screenshot it, it comes out OK. I'm going to have to guess that means the Mac doesn't know what to do with it when screenshotting from a "strange" profile.

[image]

If I generate a brand new image manually, sRGB right through…

PASTED to Safari…
[image]

POSTED to Safari
[image]

Then it reads as 255,0,0 in Photoshop, also on my Digital Colour Meter & when posted in here. Perfect workflow management.

I can still only draw the conclusion that there is something mis-calibrated in your workflow. It is not inherent in the Mac, nor in Photoshop.

[back in a sec to post via Chrome…]

PASTED into Chrome

[image]

POSTED into Chrome

[image]

***Conclusion***
**Throw Chrome away & use a proper browser. That's rubbish.**

Comment: Waht if the huion is not actulally sRGB. So then screenshotting the color on huion should react with less than 255 because the thing is relative. Yeah though crome IS rubbish

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. It sounds really silly but I think the problem is screenshotting/pasting.

When I use Shift+Control+Command+4 and directly paste it here:

[image]

When I use Shift+Command+4 and open the screenshot in Photoshop, crop it and upload here:

[image]

I'm still not entirely sure why it works like that, but I think Mac's screenshot process takes the monitor's profile into account, but when pasted directly into Chrome it only passes the raw values and discards the profile.

Comment: Paste it into Safari instead. Chrome & Firefox are notoriously poor for image profiles. BTW, the first image is still miles out, the 2nd is acceptable. The profiles on the posted images are 1) sRGB 2) Huion Kanvas Pro 16-2 [I've no idea what that is, as a profile]. The Mac's screenshotting is remarkably accurate, btw, if the screen is correctly profiled & calibrated.

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know, everything works correctly. Mac/Chrome/Photoshop all display the correct color (as calibrated). The only "wrong" thing happened is that when pasted directly into Chrome, Mac discards the color profile instead of "applying" it. If I save the screenshot and upload it, instead of directly pasting it, everything works as expcted.

Comment: @Tetsujin on Windows10 at least, Firefox seems to be the most accurate. Safari isn't an option for Windows users at all.

Comment: @BillyKerr -  Firefox has a weird profile setting, which is off by default. It was discovered whilst investigating a QA on photo.se - https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/124357/57929 Once that's 'on' it should be fine. TBH, I only really use Safari - it's the most Mac-like… of course, & I don't trust Chrome as far as I can spit it. I prefer a business model based on trying to sell me more hardware, not based on selling advertising ;)

Comment: See below for some tests. Conclusion: Chrome is rubbish.